# How to handle variables correcly in C# composition?

Tags: c#

What is the correct implementation of composition here?
I have a class Cat, which with contains _gallonsOfMilkEaten variable, because only cats drink milk. Then I also have an Animal class with Age, because all animals have certain age.
Now, I need to use the Age variable in both Cat and Dog classes.

Should I do it like this:

```
class Animal
{
    public float Age = 35;
}

class Cat
{
    private float _gallonsOfMilkEaten;
    private Animal _animal = new Animal();

    public void Meow()
    {
         Debug.log("This dog ate "+_gallonsOfMilkEaten+" gallons of milk and is " + _animal.Age+" years old." )}
    }
}


class Dog
{
    private float _bonesBurried;
    private Animal _animal = new Animal();

    public void Woof()
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

Or like this, where each of them has their own definiton of the variable?:

```
class Animal
{

}

class Cat
{
    private float _gallonsOfMilkEaten;
    private Animal _animal = new Animal();
    private float _age = 35;

    public void Meow()
    {
         Debug.log("This dog ate "+_gallonsOfMilkEaten+" gallons of milk and is " + _age+" years old." )}
    }
}


class Dog
{
    private float _bonesBurried;
    private Animal _animal = new Animal();
    private float _age = 35;

    public void Woof()
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't dog and cat both inherit from animal, where animal has an age? (it's the old "is a" or "has a" test.)

Answer (score 2):

First, the code makes sense in case you have a good reason to use composition instead of inheritance. Inheritance should be the default choice since dogs and cats `ARE` animals not `HAVE` animals.

You should keep the age in `Animal` class, if you don't then what's the point of having this class? However, you should not define it as a public field, a public read only property is preferred:

```
class Animal {
    private float _age = 35;
    public float Age {
       get {
         return this._age;
       }
    }
}    
class Cat {
    private float _gallonsOfMilkEaten;
    private Animal _animal = new Animal();

    public void Meow() {
         Debug.log("This dog ate "+_gallonsOfMilkEaten+" gallons of milk and is " + _animal.Age +" years old." )}
    }
} 
class Dog {
    private float _bonesBurried;
    private Animal _animal = new Animal();

    public void Woof() {
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: As noted in the comments to the question, it would make substantially more sense for `Cat` and `Dog` to *inherit* `Animal` rather than compose one in.  Cats don't *have* an animal, they *are* an animal.

Comment: `Age` wouldn't be accessible in this example as `protected` unless you inherited from `Animal`.

Comment: And, if you inherit it, it makes much more sense to leave it `public`.  (Though properties are good)

Comment: @Ian McLaird  I also noted that at the end of the answer but OP is explicitly saying that he wants composition. Looks like a practice or something.

Comment: But even with this setup, you can't ask a `Cat` how old it is, unless the `Cat` delegates the call to its internal `Animal` member.

Comment: @Ian McLaird Using compositon doesn't fit the example but once we accept that, I don't see the problem with the internal call between Cat and Animal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post an opposing view.  While you specifically asked for composition, this particular use case doesn't really make much sense.  `Cat`s and `Dog`s don't *have* animals, they *are* animals, so you should really use inheritance here, not composition.

```
class Animal
{
    public float Age {get; protected set; }
}
```

Then your `Cat` and `Dog` classes look like this

```
class Cat : Animal
{
    private float _gallonsOfMilkEaten;

    public void Meow()
    {
        Debug.log("This dog ate " + _gallonsOfMilkEaten + " gallons of milk and is " + Age + " years old." )}
    }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    private float _bonesBurried;

    public void Woof()
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

This allows `Cat` and `Dog` to use the `Age` member as though it were composited into them (because it is), but doesn't needlessly repeat the nesting of the `Animal` as a member.  In your specific use case, this is almost certainly what you really want.  In *other* cases, there are times where composition is better.  Here, for example, `Animal` *has an* `Age`, but an `Animal` is not a `float`.

Comment: In practice, inheritance is always preferred for this kind of problems. But in reality, there are cases that you can't or you don't want to use inheritance,  sometimes you need to sacrifice pure OO.